# ECLIPSE/GWT - Sending username and password

Tags: eclipse, gwt, authentication

I want to create a service of login and in order to do so, I'm trying to send to my local server a username and a password.
I generated with GWT a project sample code, and in myProject.java I can see the box where I can insert the username input:

```
final TextBox nameField = new TextBox();
```

Then, I made another TextBox named passField, where to put the password.
I don't understand one thing: the request to the server and the sending of the String contanining the username. If I want to send a String username and another String password, do I have to make two requests to my local server or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a request with both username and password. Declare you service method like this:

```
public void login(String username, String password);
```

and the async version like this:

```
public void login(String username, String password, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
```

I suggest you to use [PasswordTextBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PasswordTextBox.html) for password fields.